# Python & tkinter: canvas.lift and canvas.lower on overlapping buttons does not work

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I created two overlapping buttons on a canvas, using tkinter and python 3.4:

[image: button1 is below button2]

Now I would like to bring button1 to the front (the button you cannot see right now, because it is under button2)

```
self.canvas.lift(self.button1)
```

But for some reason this does not work. Just nothing happens. Also lowering button2 has no effect. Can you tell me why?

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400, background="bisque")
        self.canvas.create_text(50,10, anchor="nw", text="Click to lift button1")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.click_on_canvas)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.canvas, text="button1")        
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.canvas, text="button2")

        x = 40
        self.canvas.create_window(x, x, window=self.button1)
        self.canvas.create_window(x+5, x+5, window=self.button2)



    def click_on_canvas(self, event):

        print("lifting", self.button1)
        self.canvas.lift(self.button1)
        self.canvas.lower(self.button2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of calling `lift()` on the canvas, you need to call it on the widget instance directly:

```
def click_on_canvas(self, event):
    print("lifting", self.button1)
    self.button1.lift()
    self.button2.lower()   # Not necessary to both lift and lower
```

This is only true for widgets displayed via a window on your canvas.

If you were to draw objects such as lines or rectangles, you would use `lift()` or `tag_raise()` on the canvas instance  as you were doing before.

Comment: btw: you don't have to use `button1.lift()` and `button2.lower()` at the same time. You can use `button1.lift()` **or** `button2.lower()`.

Comment: Thanks, jkdc. That did the trick. I was tag_raise()ing other stuff on the canvas and thought windows worked the same way.